# background thread updates variable and causes index out of bounds swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, indexoutofboundsexception

I have a textField which executes a server request every time the user types a new character into the textField and dynamically displays search results to the user. These are stored in the `search_results` array. I also run the following line of code on the array to determine if any value occurs twice.

```
let duplicate_array = (search_results.filter{ $0.name == search_results[indexPath.row].name })
```

The problem is that if I type quickly enough, the `search_results` array is updated from the background thread and I get a `indexOutOfBounds` exception on this code as the `indexPath.row` no longer fits in the size of the updated `search_results`. Is there any way I can prevent this from happening, I already delayed the execution of the search query so that it is executed maximum every `0.3` seconds, and not more often, however this still happens occasionally if the `search_results` size is large.

Answer (score 0):

As you've explained, the index out of bounds is caused by `indexPath.row` being no longer fits in the size of the updated `search_results`.

You can prevent this by checking if the `search_results.count` is greater than `indexPath.row`. If it's not greater that `indexPath.row`, then trigger the results reload, for example by calling `collectionView.reloadData()` if you're using UICollectionView. (Without accessing the `search_results[indexPath.row]`.